# how to check a string for a specific character

Tags: c

I want my function to check whether my string has a specific character.
It shall return the pointer to the last appearance of it. But when I start my program it gives me storage access error.

```
char *strrchr(const char *s, int c) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == c)
            index = i;
    }
    if (index)
        return NULL;
    else
        return s[index];
}
```

Comment: `return s[index];` ==> `return &s[index];`

Comment: Always compile your code with warnings enabled and *pay attention to them*. If you're using GCC, compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: @efekctive OP wrote "the last appearing of it."

Comment: @efekctive Note the OP is implementing str**r**chr.

Comment: I did not read last appearing. Deleting previous one

Comment: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
         return s[index]; ist the only warning i get

Comment: Also note that your logic is backwards on the return.

Comment: i just read it. thanks :)

Comment: What about starting from the end? It will break on first successful if. You know the starting address, and the length. Short of time to post the code.

Comment: ur code has a big problem and that is that you return NULL if index is 0. what if c occur in the 0th element of the array??? you will return NULL which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I made 2 fixes. The value of index should be initialized to -1 so it can't confused with a valid index into the string. Also , you need to return "address of" s[index] : use &s[index]

```
char *strrchr (const char *s, int c){
    int index=0;   // change to -1
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++){
        if(s[i]==c)
            index=i;
    }
    if(index == -1) // check for -1
        return NULL;
    else
        return &s[index];
}
```

Comment: The type of `i` should be `size_t`, which can be larger than `int`. The function fails to return the offset of the end of string for `c == '\0'`.

Comment: @chqrlie The function isn't designed to return an offset.

Comment: OK, The function fails to return a pointer to the string's null terminator for `c == '\0'`. You also need to cast the return value as `return (char*)&s[index];` to remove the constness.

Comment: `strrchr()` is a standard function, changing its prototype is probably not expected. The implementation requires a cast, just like that of `strchr()` and `strstr()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation has multiple problems:

- You return `NULL` when the character is **found** at a non zero offset.
- You return the character at `str[index]` instead of its address `&str[index]` which can be written `str + index`.
- You cannot distinguish failure to find the character from success at finding it at offset `0`.
- Type `int` for `index` is incorrect: the length of a string can exceed the maximum value of type `int`. You should use type `size_t` or increment the pointer.
- You cannot find the final `'\0'` when `c == 0`.
- `strrchr()` is supposed to convert its `int` argument `c` to a `char` before scanning.

Here is a simplified and corrected version:

```
char *strrchr(const char *s, int c) {
    char *result = NULL;

    for (c = (char)c;; s++) {
        if (*s == c) {
            /* found the character, use a cast to remove constness */
            result = (char *)s;
        }
        if (*s == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return logic isn't correct. You are returning NULL when you found a match.
Otherwise, returning a `char` instead of a pointer to the index.

You also don't need to calculate the string length when you can make use of the null byte.

```
char *strrchr (const char *s, int c){
    size_t index = 0;
    bool found = false;     
    c = (char) c;

    if (!c) return (char*)s + strlen(s);

    for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if(s[i] == c) {
            index = i;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found) return (char*)s + index;

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: @TanujYadav I obviously didn't test it - fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: @chqrlie That's true. I never understood (or remember that strrchr *can* handle null byte) the reason for that extra allowance or even if it's ever useful considering `s` needs to be a null terminated string (why would anyone want to use `strrchr` to find the null byte?). Fortunately, it's easy to fix. Thanks.

Comment: Why the semantics is defined as such is a good question, maybe for consistency with `strchr()`. Which of course does not provide a complete answer.  Note that `c` should be converted to `(char)` as specified in the C Standard.  `'\0'` can be handled without a special case: just move the test for end of string at the end of the `for` body.

Comment: "should be converted to (char)" - or rather unsigned char. "special case" - I know but it's unnecessary to do the `if` test when c is 0.

Comment: @P.P.: I'm afraid converting to `unsigned char` is incorrect if the type `char` is signed by default: `*"\377" == (unsigned char)'\377'` would be false because `-1 != 255`.

Comment: @chqrlie It's no more "incorrect" than casting to `char`. `strchr()` doesn't work with multi-byte chars (values outside CHAR_MIN to CHAR_MAX range) - your example is flawed. I know C standard says "converted to a char" but it doesn't really matter in comparisons. As it'll again be converted to `int` in the actual comparison done in `strchr()`. There's no way to compare something as "char". So, this makes no difference whether it's cast to char or unsigned char. I prefer `unsigned char` as it's consistent with the requirements of some standard functions in `stdio.h`, `string.h`, and `ctype.h`.

Comment: @P.P.: you are mistaken: it does make a difference to cast `c` as `char` and it is different from casting as `unsigned char`: `strrchr("a", 'a' + 256)` should not return `NULL`, but it will if you remove the cast.

Comment: @chqrlie "... should not return NULL, but it will if you remove the cast" - I think you are implying I said the cast is *not* required at all - which I didn't. All I am arguing is casting to either `char` or `unsigned char` is totally fine in this case. Copy-pasted the code from my answer and it behaves as expected for your input: http://ideone.com/eozp2o

Comment: @P.P.: casting to `char` or `unsigned char` has a different effect for negative values. The example I gave is exactly pertinent to this case: `strrchr("\377", '\377')` will erroneously return `NULL` with your cast as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chqrlie You are assuming `strchr()` is supposed to work with wide chars/multibytes. I see no supporting evidence for that in the C and POSIX standards. The only relevant info I find is the Linux man page which states [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html):`Here "character" means "byte"; these functions do not work with wide or multibyte characters.`.

Comment: @P.P.: I am not assuming anything about wide characters at all. The example `strrchr("\377", '\377')` is straight forward: if `char` is 8-bit signed, `'\377`` has  a value of `-1` and casting it to `unsigned char` produces the value `255` which will compare unequal to any character from the string because as you correctly stated, the comparison is done on the promoted values and the characters from the string are promoted to `int` with values between `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX`, namely `-1` for the first character, whereas `c` has the value `255`.

Comment: @P.P.: The linux man page for `strchr()` is not precise enough, *Here "character" means "byte"; these functions do not work with wide or multibyte characters*... The C Standard is more explicit: *The `strchr` function locates the first occurrence of `c` (converted to a `char`) in the string pointed to by `s`. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string.*

Comment: @chqrlie -1 seems to prove your point. Surprisingly glibc seems to cast to unsigned char. (Not sure if I am looking at a wrong code though). But I am convinced that you are correct. LSNED! Sorry for the delay in getting your point!

Comment: @P.P.: The glibc indeed casts to `unsigned char`, but the resulting value is only compared to `'\0'` or passed to `strchr`, hence it behaves the same. Their generic implementation of `strchr()` also casts to `unsigned char`, but the `char *` pointer is also converted to `unsigned char *`, so again the resulting behavior is the same.